# Checking if item lore contains contains string (loren.contains("§eSigned from "))

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

### I only want to check for:

```
if (lore.contains("§eSigned of ")) {
```

### but it doesn't get that it does contain "§eSigned of "

I wrote a Minecraft Command `/sign` you can add a lore to an item ("Signed of *playerrank* | *playername*").
Then i wanted to add an `/unsign` command to remove this lore.

```
ItemStack is = p.getItemInHand();
ItemMeta im = is.getItemMeta();
List<String> lore = im.hasLore() ? im.getLore() : new ArrayList<String>();
        
if (lore.contains("§eSigned of " + getChatName(p))) { // this line is important!
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int size = lore.size();
        lore.remove(size - 1);                    
    }

    im.setLore(lore);
    is.setItemMeta(im);

    p.setItemInHand(is);
    sendMessage(p, "§aThis item is no longer signed");
} else {
    sendMessage(p, "§aThis item is not signed!");
}
return CommandResult.None;
```

Everything works fine until you e.g. change your name. than you can't remove the sign because `getChatName(p)` has changed.
To fix this i only want to check

```
if (lore.contains("§eSigned of ")) {
```

but than it doesn't get it and returns false. (it says lore does not contain "§eSigned of ")
I tried a lot but it only works with the string "§eSigned of " and `getChatName(p)`.
As the documentation "contains" searches for the specific string so it should work as I thought right?

Add:
`getChatName(p)` returns the rank of the player and the playername like: "Member | domi"
`sendMessage(p, "")` sends a simple message in the Minecraft chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you run into is that `contains(String)` looks for a matching string. What you search for is a check if any string in the list starts with "§eSigned of ".

I would suggest adding a function `isSignedItem` like this:

```java
private boolean isSignedItem(List<String> lore) {
    for (String st : lore)
        if (st.startsWith("§eSigned of "))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

and then to use this function to check if the item is signed or not:

```java
    [...]
    List<String> lore = im.hasLore() ? im.getLore() : new ArrayList<String>();
    if (isSignedItem(lore)) { // this line is important!
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int size = lore.size();
            lore.remove(size - 1);
        }
        [...]
```

Comment: Thank you! Using startsWith() really fixed my problem :)